# Is there a way to change color space of all separate image texture nodes using python?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, filmic-blender

I have tried it earlier but I can only find a way to change the color space of a single image texture node using python so, I want to ask if there's a way to change it for s**eparate image texture** nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import bpy


def change_color_space(object, color_space='sRGB'):
    '''
    Change the color space of all the image texture node.
    
    object (bpy.types.Object) - The object to take material from.
    color_space (enum in [‘Filmic Log’, ‘Filmic sRGB’, ‘Linear’, ‘Linear ACES’, ‘Linear ACEScg’, ‘Non-Color’, ‘Raw’, ‘sRGB’, ‘XYZ’], default ‘sRGB’) - Color space in the image file, to convert to and from when saving and loading the image.
    '''
    if object.material_slots:
        for slot in object.material_slots:
            if slot.material:
                node_tree = slot.material.node_tree

                for node in node_tree.nodes:
                    if node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE' and node.image:
                        node.image.colorspace_settings.name = color_space
                        
                
change_color_space(bpy.context.object, 'Non-Color')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, I had two more questions:-

1. Can you suggest as code for changing the color spaces of particularly the image textures attached to albedo/base color of the Principled BSDF of all materials?

2. Is there a code through which I can remove the image textures attached to Alpha of Principled BSDF of all materials?

Comment: Learn some blender API